# 2019 MacBook Pro 16-Inch Desktop Manager hangs/freezes whenever an app asks for permissions

Tags: permission, performance

I have a fresh install of macOS 11.5.2 with nothing crazy. Just some Adobe apps, Office, Parallels, iStat, etc.

Seemingly at random, if an app pops up a directory permission, there is a 50/50 chance that the entire desktop environment will hang. The system is not actually frozen, and the apps seem to keep running just fine, but clicks and keyboard input just cease to work along with the window manager. Meanwhile, notifications will still pop up, sound still works, and I can still move my mouse around and see tooltips populate.

I am able to close the notebook and open it again. Even the login screen pops up correctly with the fingerprint reader correctly functioning. But once I am back at the desktop, I am again unable to click anything or use the keyboard.

The only way to fix the issue is to force a shutdown by holding the power button down.

I have tried running first aid on the drive, booting the built-in Apple diagnostic and so on, but nothing seems to be wrong.

Any ideas on what may be causing this or what logs I should be looking at?

Comment: I'm confused when you say "the entire desktop environment will hang" and the "window manager" will "cease to work" but then "apps seem to keep running just fine". Which is it?

Comment: Can you download Etrechek https://cdn.etrecheck.com/EtreCheckPro.zip and scan your Mac?

Comment: @pion It's hard to explain. While elements of the UI continue to animate/function, MOST input is completely blocked. For example, I can see my iStat menu widgets continue to function along with notification banners continuing to pop up, but I cannot interact with the UI in any way outside of scrolling whatever window was currently active.

Comment: @Jean_JD Here you go: https://pastebin.com/xsu4nn1S

Comment: @Roswell Do you remember when the problem appears? Maybe that's correspond to à software installation.

Comment: @Roswell Do you have access to a second computer? We can do a lot of debugging if you can ssh into your target machine from there.